# How can I read a table in google docs and then change its cells background color

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I want to change the background colour of a table cell in google docs if it matches a value. Here is the image of the table which I want to match
[image]

Here is my code where I am getting this table:

```
   for(var dex= 0; dex <= 5 ; dex++){
    var row = mytable.getRow(dex);
    var res = row.getText();
  
    if (res[dex]=="B+"){
      mytable.getCell().setBackgroundColor("#FFFF00");
    }
  }
```

It is not colouring the particular with B+.
Please someone help.

Comment: In your screenshot there is no data. Please share some test data and expected results.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the quesiton correctly: Do you want to know at what time a student submits a form?